# jQuery UI Autocomplete - Search based on a json node

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to search based on a school name, once the school name is selected populate a form.

I'm having a few issues searching on that particular jSON node, which in this case is **name** I have got the JSON response working, But it's just returning everything back. Not the specific term.

An example of my jSON Data :

```
[
  {
    "name":"The Mendip School",
    "ta":"ta552023",
    "address1":"Longfellow Road",
    "address2":"Radstock",
    "town":"",
    "postcode":"BA3 3AL"
  }
]
```

My jQuery is as follows :

```
// School Search....
var data_source = 'schools.json';

$(".school_name").autocomplete({
    source: function ( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: data_source,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response( $.map( data, function ( item )
                {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
        window.location = ui.item.value;
        return false;
    }
});
```

How do I modify my JQuery to search on the name field? I will also need to get the other fields to populate input fields.

Thanks

Comment: You've mixed up the response object that's passed to the source callback, and the response event.  Take a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source and http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that may suit your needs:

```
$("#school_name").autocomplete({
    source: function ( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
    $.getJSON("/schools.json?term=" + request.term, function (data) {

            var x = $.grep(data, function (item, index) {
                    return matcher.test( item.name );
                });
                console.log(x);
            response($.map(x, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.name
                    };
                }));
        });
}
```

The code above will filter the data using the regex(`new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" )`). This regex will search for names which start-begin(^) with the typed text(by the user). The 'i' in the regex is for case-insensitive while the escapeRegex will just escape any special characters in user input.

You can also use your code and do the respective changes, I think it will also work. I just prefer to use $.getJSON. Take care of the #school_name for id(in your code you are using '.')

Try it here: http://jsbin.com/vawozutepu